# Pandas autocorr returning different calcs then my own autocorrelation function;

Tags: python, pandas

This is more out of curiosity then necessity. I've attempted to implement my own autocorrelation function in native python. To double check it, I compared it to pandas auto_corr function, but I'm receiving different results. Could someone explain to me how Pandas calculates the auto_corr in a series and possibly explain the difference?

```
 def my_auto_corr(x):
      result = []
      lag = len(x)//2
      for i in range(0,lag):
          corr = 0
          var = 0
          for j in range(0,len(x) - i):
              x1 = x[j] - ave(x)
              x2 = x[j + i] - ave(x)
              corr += x1*x2
              var  += x1**2
          result.append(corr/var)
      return result

 def ave(x):
      total = 0
      count = len(x)
      for i in range(count):
          total += x[i]
      return total/count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas does the Pearson correlation between the Series and its shifted self. I think the way that you are calculating correlation in your code is wrong, that is the way that I would reproduce Pandas autocorr using a for loop:

```
def avg(x):
 return sum(x)/len(x)

def my_auto_corr(x, lag):
    series = x[lag:]
    series_auto = x[:-lag]
    corr = 0
    var = 0
    var_x1 = 0
    var_x2 = 0
    for j in range(len(series)):
        x1 = series[j] - avg(series)
        x2 = series_auto[j] - avg(series_auto)
        corr += x1*x2
        var_x1  += x1**2
        var_x2 += x2**2
    return corr/((var_x1*var_x2) ** 0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and clarifying the difference. The method I employed above isn't wrong, it's calculating the autocorrelation coefficient - see Forecasting: Principals and Practice, [link] (https://otexts.com/fpp2/autocorrelation.html) - not the Pearson correlation coefficient.